# "ERROR: Stack's declared dependencies are missing calculated dependencies"

Tags: ros, ros-release, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run this command: `rosrun release create.py wu_ros_tools 0.1.0 electric`
using the electric version of the release script.

The stack file I'm using is [here in my repository](http://code.google.com/p/wu-robotics/source/browse/branches/stable/wu_ros_tools/stack.xml?spec=svn2226&r=2226).

However, after the above command checks out the repo, I get this error.

```
ERROR: Stack's declared dependencies are missing calculated dependencies:
geometry
visualization
diagnostics_monitors
common_msgs
```

...but I DID declare those stacks, didn't I?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43826/%22error:-stack%27s-declared-dependencies-are-missing-calculated-dependencies%22/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2012-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Might there be local changes in your working copy?

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-09-16**:
Must've just de-synched. Works now.